# updating a column based on a condition without using .loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update values of a column based on a condition. However, it only works when I use `.loc`. I wonder if I can do it without using `.loc`.

Here is the code without .loc (I do not receive errors, but values are not updated):

```
mask1 = GDP['Country Name'] == "Korea, Rep."
GDP[mask1]['Country Name'] = "South Korea"
```

Here is the code with .loc that is working fine:

```
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == "Korea, Rep.", 'Country Name'] = "South Korea"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're performing [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) basically you're operating on a copy in the first instance and not a view (with `.loc`), in the latest versions of pandas it should raise a warning for this

Comment: @EdChum thanks. As I understand .loc should be preferred over chained indexing..

Comment: Well it depends on your use case, the problem is that the first case is ambiguous, are you intending to work on a copy or a view, in the second case it's clear you want to work on a view. Generally one should call `copy()` to make an explicit copy, after which it's clear you want to operate on a copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Country Name'] = df['Country Name'].replace({'Korea, Rep.':'South Korea'})
```

**Timings**:

```
In [220]: %timeit (rep(GDP))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.79 ms per loop

In [221]: %timeit (orig(GDP1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
import pandas as pd

GDP = pd.DataFrame({'Country Name':['Korea, Rep.','aa','ss']})
#[30000 rows x 1 columns]
GDP = pd.concat([GDP]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (GDP)

GDP1 = GDP.copy()

def rep(GDP):
    GDP['Country Name'] = GDP['Country Name'].replace({'Korea, Rep.':'South Korea'})
    return (GDP)

def orig(GDP):
    GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == "Korea, Rep.", 'Country Name'] = "South Korea"
    return (GDP)


print (rep(GDP))    
print (orig(GDP1))
```

Comment: You are recommending this because it runs faster?

Comment: Hard question, but I can add some timings.

Comment: What is size of your `DataFrame` ?

Comment: I think `replace` is a bit faster.